# calendarViewShown is not being honored on Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, datepicker, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working through The Big Nerd Ranch's Android Guide. In the
assignment Criminal Intent I am using DatePicker with following
layout.

On pre-5.0 devices, calendar is not shown in DatePicker as defined in
the layout but Android 5.0 ignores this and shows a calendar. Any idea
what might be going on here?

Full code is available on [Github](https://github.com/donniezazen/The-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Guide/tree/master/CriminalIntent).

**dialog_date.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" >
</DatePicker>
```

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
package com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent.date";
    private Date mDate;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),
                resultCode, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);
        // Create a Calendar to get the year, month, and day
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // calendar.setTime(mDate);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v
                .findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePicker);
        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
                    int day) {
                // Translate year, month, day into a Date object using a
                // calendar
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute)
                        .getTime();
                // Update argument to preserve selected value on rotation
                getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
            }
        });

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                            }
                        }).create();

    }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi, This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854762/android-material-design-inline-datepicker-issue.

Comment: @DavidSchofield Thanks David. It is weird that Google doesn't update documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26855485/3034693)

You have to use both `android:calendarViewShown="false"` and `android:datePickerMode="spinner"`.

This solves it.

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" >
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: but with it you get an ugly warning :( its just use in api 21, current min is 16. I guess i can ignore it.

Comment: oh i just saw even more. it gives an error: `rror: No resource identifier found for attribute 'datePickerMode' in package 'android'`

Comment: @Mulgard Did you find the documentation?

Comment: there is no option 'datepickermode'

Comment: @Mulgard just add `tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"` to silent the warning.

Comment: @akhyar a better solution, to avoid the warning, would be to have a another folder (layout-v21) for api level 21 and above as indicate [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me

```
new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, this, year,month, day);
```

Comment: I used the same but that way the buttons on the bottom won't have the new material style.