# Style DatePicker on a android tablet on lollipop

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have an application which use a DatePicker & TimePicker.

On my nexus 7 2013 on lollipop, I've another layout :

[image: layout on the nexus 7 2013 lollipop]

but i expect that layout (which is on a galaxy tab 2 on ics) :

[image: layout on galaxy tab ics]

my xml ressource is :

```
    <TableRow>
        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dateoperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/heurearrivee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/heuredepart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
```

how can I correct that layout ?

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212267/calendarviewshown-is-not-being-honored-on-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: you are right. a huge thank you. didn't found it. I voted to close my issue.