# DatePicker dialog not working propely and not looking nice

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-datepicker

I am trying to use a DatePicker:
My code is:

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePicker);
        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
                    int day) {
                mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
            }
        });
```

But when I select a date the `onDateChanged` method is never called. After googling I found that if I changed my date picker layout to include: `android:datePickerMode="spinner" />` and remove `android:calendarViewShown="false"` the `onDateChanged` is called and the code works but the date picker dialog is really bad looking.
My layout is:

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
    <!--  android:calendarViewShown="false" -->
```

So why is the calenderViewShown attribute causing a problem and how can I improve the look of the date picker UI dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use datepicker dialog than there's no need to use DatePicker just do it this way:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SignUpActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            try {
                Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse(year+"-"+(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth);                            


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));      

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);   
    datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);        
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: So does that mean that DatePicker is "useless"?

Comment: In your example how do I start this from the fragment. I see you bind it with an activity instead.

Comment: If you need a dialog than its feasible to use DatePickerDialog and you can use DatePicker view in case you want to make your own dialog or any customization according to your need.

Comment: For fragment you can use getActivity() instead.

Comment: But where should I add this snippet? Right now I have my code in `public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the fragment and I do: `View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);.....return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).....`

Comment: You can make a function and place the code in it and can call this function on any button click or anywhere according to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this library : [Beautiful DatePicker UI](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker)

If on AS, add this in dependencies : compile `'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'`

Also,as pointed at this question : [Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212267/calendarviewshown-is-not-being-honored-on-android-5-0-lollipop)

You can use this to solve the issue.

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" >
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: So does that mean that DatePicker is "useless"?

Comment: It means you are beautifying the UI because you don't like the original look provided by google.

Comment: The DatePicker using the attribute of spinner is bad. If in my layout I remove `android:datePickerMode="spinner"`  and add `android:calendarViewShown="false" instead the UI is ok

Comment: Exactly. So it's your choice, you can design your application the way you want. SO can only give you suggestions.

Comment: I don't follow you. So the `android:calendarViewShown=false` is broken? That is my question