# Hide Calendarview from DatePicker programmatically in API 21

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm having the same issue as this thread: [Android Material Design Inline Datepicker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854762/android-material-design-inline-datepicker-issue), but I am not using an XML layout, instead I'm building the DatePicker programmatically.

This is the code I am using but is not working

```
DatePicker dpView = new DatePicker(ctx);
dpView.setCalendarViewShown(false);
dpView.setSpinnersShown(true);
```

how can I make it work?

Comment: Here is an alternative solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185405/5730321

Comment: Setting spinner mode will not weork for all the APIs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem in Android 5.0 is the "mode" which determines whether to use a calendar or not is read at construct time, and in code you can't set the mode until *after* it has been constructed, thus it's too late. (Source is here: [DatePicker Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/DatePicker.java?av=f))

My solution was to create my own reusable DatePicker layout that specifies the "no calendar" mode, and construct my DateTimes programmatically with that layout instead of Android's default.

Bottom line is, create a "DatePicker.axml" file, put it in the resources folder, and paste the following as its contents:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:calendarViewShown="false"
          android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

and declare it wherever you need in code like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From( Activity );
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)inflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.DatePicker, null );
```

Comment: Hi @JHawkzz, that was what I did, but I forgot to post the answer, thanks, I will mark this as the answer anyway, because it is :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the mark, glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: @JHawkzz Can you explain in more details? Specially the inflater part? How can we integrate it in DialogFragment? and Why axml??

Comment: android:datePickerMode="spinner" doesn't work on android 7.0

Answer (score 24):

If you have to set it up programmatically in a DatePickerFragment just set this:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, this, year, month, day);
```

with whatever style you like.

Comment: Tried and tested this solution with DatePickerDialog. It works.

Comment: If anyone has problems with two boxes drawn around the date picker or other style issues, check out [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39875089/410143).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Worked with material design.

Comment: It is deprecated now

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31610267/410143) from user [Luismi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887635/luismi):

The theme `Theme.Holo.Dialog` or `Theme.Holo.Dialog.MinWidth` might cause problems like two boxes drawn around the date picker.

Instead you should the theme `Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoFrame` to prevent this. The theme might not be accessable from your code, so just create your own theme:

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

Edit: The better way to fix this problem is to use the [SpinnerDatePicker library](https://github.com/drawers/SpinnerDatePicker) that recreates the old design.

Comment: Theme.Holo.Dialog is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I simply changed my AppTheme(v21) style and worked:

```
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="PickerDialogCustom" parent="AlertDialogCustom">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyLight500</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:positiveButtonText">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:negativeButtonText">@color/greyDark200</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/negativeButton</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
</style>
```