# Datepicker dialog without calendar visualization in lollipop [spinner mode]?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-5.0-lollipop

I read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
but now in lollipop appears the calendar (it is ok for an event but horrible for set a date of birth, I would a spinner mode.) and I can't remove it!
In layout It's easy with this property:

```
 <DatePicker
 datePickerMode="spinner"...>
```

but from code of the DatePickerDialog if I try to set

```
dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

These properties do not work and the calendar continues to appear!

```
public static class MyDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        int pYear;
        int pDay;
        int pMonth;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dialogDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
            dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            return dialogDatePicker;
            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            pYear = year;
            pDay = day;
            pMonth = month;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try putting `android:calendarViewShown="false"` in xml

Comment: This is duplicated: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31610267/1887635

Answer (score 58):

DatePickerDialog uses the dialog theme specified by your activity theme. This is a fully-specified theme, which means you need to re-specify any attributes -- such as the date picker style -- that you've set in your activity theme.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** Due to [Issue 222208](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222208), this will not work in Android N / API 24. It has already been fixed in the platform for the next release. There is no workaround available for API 24 devices.

Comment: Only way this works un a fragment, thanks. Now to figure out how to make it work both under and over api v21.

Comment: @alanv When I apply the above `MyDialogTheme` for `DatePickerDialog`, the `OK` and `CANCEL` buttons are of blue colour. How can I change that colour?

Comment: Set `colorAccent` like you would on your activity theme.

Comment: The theme should extend `android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert` (or the `Light` variant) or else the dialog just wraps the spinner width.

Comment: @Mukesh Same issue as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222208. It has been fixed for a future release, but there is no workaround for dialogs.

Comment: @Thanks It's Working For  api level>= 21

Comment: how to change the background color?

Answer (score 42):

Apply the Holo_theme in the code level got worked for me.

```
new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,this, year,month, day);
```

Comment: Great answer! android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog looks much better though

Comment: @WaqasRaja Same issue.. did you find any solution?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comments , It is not working on API 24 , but its working for older API level. Can anybody tell How to make it work on API 24 ?

Comment: android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog is deprecated now

Comment: It still works on API 25 for me. Not sure why API 24 is a one-off issue. In regards to the deprecation, yes it is deprecated, you are not supposed to use Holo themes, but it is highly unlikely they will remove it from the SDK, further it is not like you are using deprecated code, all that style is doing is using `<item name="datePickerMode">spinner</item>`

Answer (score 20):

I think the best solution to this problem is define a new style in the XML file and then use it programatically in the code.

Though @alanv [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28773976/1237141) is perfect and will work correctly, the problem with it is that it will be applied for all the Date pickers. Suppose you have one DatePicker where you need to show Calendar view, and another DatePicker where you need to show spinner view, this will not work.

So define a new style in a styles.xml. Create this file in a folder named values-v21 (see naming structure [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)), since these attributes are introduced post lollipop only. Before lollipop, there was only spinner mode.

```
 <style name="CustomDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

And finally, use it in the code like this

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
    R.style.CustomDatePickerDialogTheme, this, year, month, day);
return datePickerDialog;
```

Comment: You should also provide the the corresponding entry in your `style.xml` in the values folder. Otherwise the DatePicker has the wrong styling on pre-Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a library to create the old "spinner" style DatePicker which is just three NumberPicker put together:

https://github.com/drawers/SpinnerDatePicker

[image: spinner date picker]

First, define a style:

```
<style name="NumbePickerStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">22dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then,

```
new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
        .context(MainActivity.this)
        .callback(MainActivity.this)
        .spinnerTheme(spinnerTheme)
        .year(year)
        .monthOfYear(monthOfYear)
        .dayOfMonth(dayOfMonth)
        .build()
        .show();
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of this library</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Add the attribute calendarViewShown and set it to false:

```
<DatePicker
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/date_field"
android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a bit off-topic but provides an alternative approach with the standard `DatePicker` which can be useful to someone.
It's 2019 now and this issue still persists.

- `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` doesn't work at all the APIs
- Integrating a library for such a simple task (having quite nice material picker) is not what every developer wants.

From another point of view, the widget is quite handy, **the problem is that not all the Android users know they can open the year selection section**, which makes year selection easy:

[image]

This creates not the best UX for some users and they are having hard times with the date of birth selection (some users just swipe calendar until reach the needed year)

I ended up with a workaround solution which lets doing one of the following:

1. **Initially show user year selection view** of the DatePicker (image above), after which he navigates to the calendar view
2. Or show a regular calendar view, **with highlighting the "Year button" with the ripple** (or in another way, such as Year's background change to make it look like a button).

See the animation below on how different solutions are seen for a user:

[image]

Here is what you need:

1. Show a `DatePicker` (`DatePickerDialog` or a `DialogFragment` which creates it).
2. Retrieve the "Year" `TextView`:

   ```
   val yearTextview =dialog.findViewById<TextView>(context.resources
   ?.getIdentifier("android:id/date_picker_header_year", null, null)?: -1)
   ```
3. Do whatever you want with it, for instance:

   - Perform a click programmatically to select a year section:

   yearTextview?.performClick()

   - Show a ripple effect after showing (with setting  `yearTextview?.isPressed = true` for some period of time)
   - Change it's background etc.

Drawback: if the id will be changed in the next API's - it will require you to change it accordingly

Comment: This is an excellent approach that doesn't exactly match what the OP wants, but is perhaps the best overall solution.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
DatePickerDialog dialogDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            return dialogDatePicker;
```

removing

```
dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
```

Comment: these calls have now been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me, do a custom datelistener:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setDate(View view) {
        showDialog(999);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month-1, day);
        }
        return null;
    }
    //THIS
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

        //dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
               // .append(month).append("-").append(year));
    }
```

Comment: Mmm I will try... but now I'm using datepicker without dialog.

Answer (score 2):

All fancy stuff aside, use the DatePickerDialog constructor that takes an "int theme" parameter.
Without it, it seems to default to whichever int sets it to CalendarView mode.
With small integers (0, 1, 2, 3...) it will give you a spinner (at least in my API 19 app run on an emulator).
Basically, try 
new DatePickerDialog( getContext(), 0, this, year, month, day )
Notice the 0 (or 1, or 2, etc) there

Caution:
I'm not sure if there's a list somewhere of static theme fields, and using a hardcoded "0" instead of "Theme.HOLO_LIGHT" or whatever could make a difference on different devices, but it gets the job done somehow.

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1: Create spinner/calendar date picker layout**

.../main/res/layout/spinner_date_picker_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

.../main/res/layout/calendar_date_picker_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:datePickerMode="calendar" />
```

**Step-2: Set clickable behavior on TextView for showing Date Dialog.**

.../main/res/layout/activity_layout.xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Date"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClickDate()}"></TextView>
```

**Step-3: Show Dialog on onClickDate**

```
override fun onClickDate() {
        showDialogForDate()
}
```

**Step-4: Set DatePicker Layout into Dialog View.**

```
private fun showDialogForDate() {

    //Set spinner/calendar date picker layout
    val spinnerDatePicker = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_date_picker_layout, null)

    // On click listener for dialog buttons
    val dialogClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
        when (which) {
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> {
                activity!!.dateText.text = spinnerDatePicker.datePicker.dayOfMonth.toString() + "/" + (spinnerDatePicker.datePicker.month + 1) + "/" + spinnerDatePicker.datePicker.year
            }
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> {

            }
        }
    }

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
    builder.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.dialog_title))
        .setView(spinnerDatePicker)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", dialogClickListener)
        .create()
        .show()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/NumberPickerStyle"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Inflate this in a dialog and you are done. Although the `android:datePickerMode` may show you API 21 and high warning, it should work in previous versions of android as well, because the DatePicker style itself is an old style. I tested this implementation in API 16 and above and faced no issues.

[image: Spinner Date Picker Dialog]

Code:

```
private fun showOldDatePickerDialog() {
    with(View.inflate(this, R.layout.old_style_date_picker, null)){
        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(this)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ ->
                    Log.d("DatePicker","${this.datePicker.month.plus(1)} : ${this.datePicker.dayOfMonth} : ${this.datePicker.year}")
                }.create().also { it.show() }
    }
}
```

To change the text size add this to your styles.

```
<style name="NumberPickerStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker methods related to showing spinner and/or calendar view are deprecated from API level 24. Method setSpinnersShown(boolean shown) and setCalendarViewShown(boolean shown) are deprecated because calendar mode material style doesn't support the feature.

If you want to use material style in spinner mode, use DatePicker widget.

Apply below style to your date picker xml element to get material spinner. For more information on date picker and styles see http://www.zoftino.com/android-datepicker-example .

```
<style name="MyDatePickerSpinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#d50000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Not sure if its changed since you posted this, but you can just do android:calendarViewShown="false" in the xml file where you declared the DatePicker right along side the DatePickers other properties

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

calendatViewShown will remove the calendar view and dataPickerMode has to be set to the spinner to show the Spinner view that you need.