# Android DatePicker Spinners Not Displaying

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch Android Programming book right now. I'm currently trying to get a DatePicker fragment to display as spinners. It seems to continually display a calender view and I can't figure out why. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</DatePicker>
```

How I'm creating it:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it showing both calendar and spinner?

Comment: It's a known issue, find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185405/5730321

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

along with:

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Comment: Already user is using android:calendarViewShown="false" as mentioned in the question

Comment: This actually worked though - it looks like the problem was that I didn't have the datePickerMode listed :). Appreciate both of your help!

Comment: It doesn't work for all the devices (For instance, on Android 7.0)