# Remove the Extra day month and year on android calendar dialog

Tags: java, android

Please how do I remove the day,month and year showing on my calendar dialogue which was created programatically.

Code:

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            //   updateLabel();
            String myFormat = "MM,dd,yyyy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

           selectdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        }

    };
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I do not want the v=green part in my app. Juts the calendar. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28773976/115145, though in your case, you would set the `android:datePickerMode` to `calendar`.