# datepicker dialog can't swich to spinner on Android 7.0 device

Tags: android, datepickerdialog, android-7.0-nougat

Before `Android N`, I can use the code below to instance a `spnnier` mode `datepicker dialog`:

```
new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, null, 2016, 9, 18);
```

but the above code is not work on `Android N` device, it always show the `calander mode`, is there something different in `Android N`? How can I instance a `spinner` mode `datepicker dialog`?

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: This issue still persists. Here is an alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185405/5730321

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like : yourDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

Comment: The method is deprecated and has no effect