# datepickerdialog hide calendar and change my date picker view to standard mode

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I want to change my date picker view to standard mode

From

[image]

To

[image]

My code is

```
dateOfBirthET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);
        //setting dateSetListener
        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
                updateLabelToSave();
            }

        };

        //setting onClickListener on setDate
        dateOfBirthET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterActivity.this, date,
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


                //setting maxDate on tempCal
                long maxDate = new Date().getTime();
                tempCal.setTimeInMillis(maxDate);
                tempCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, tempCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 16);

                dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(tempCal.getTimeInMillis());

                dpd.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

I am tried this code also but not working

```
dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740657/datepicker-dialog-without-calendar-visualization-in-lollipop-spinner-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change theme you want while creating DatePickerDialog instance

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(RegisterActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog ,date,
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Working for me tested android 6.0 marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

From the [setCalendarViewShown doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setCalendarViewShown(boolean)) it says

> Calling this method has no effect when the DatePicker_datePickerMode
>   attribute is set to calendar.

And as of Android L, with the Material theme selected, the default layout of `android:datePickerMode` is calendar (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:datePickerMode))

So if you want to change your DatePickerDialog to spiner style, you must change `android:datePickerMode`

And now I see datePickerMode can not change programmatically, it can only change by config XML like

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    />
```

Therefore I think you should create a custom your DatePickerDilog layout