# how i can show traditional calendar?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to snow the traditional(Before material design) calendar in my application : counter calendar 
I use the following code and this is the output 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ5aa.png)

my code is :

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }


    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.e("Result is :", String.valueOf(year + month + day));
    }
```

i need to show this calendar .. how i can ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0WSE.png)

Comment: any body can help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datepicker dialog without calendar visualization in lollipop \[spinner mode\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740657/datepicker-dialog-without-calendar-visualization-in-lollipop-spinner-mode)