# How can I implement a calendar view similar to this

Tags: android, calendar

I want to implement a calendar view into my application so that people can choose dates. I like this calendar view which is in the google Adsense app.
[image]
How can I implement something similar? I looked around and I couldn't find the name.

I tried multiple calendar librairies but none are this clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Datepicker` like mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740657/datepicker-dialog-without-calendar-visualization-in-lollipop-spinner-mode) to achieve your wanted look.

Another solution that I can offer if you want to change the names inside the dialog is to use custom number picker like this:

**You need to add `NumberPicker` into your XML:**

```
<NumberPicker
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Create an array with your values(this will go to the number picker)**

```
String mValues[] = { "100 ", "200" };
```

**Now use this method to create number picker with custom values:**

```
 private void setNubmerPicker(NumberPicker nubmerPicker,String [] numbers ){
    nubmerPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length-1);
    nubmerPicker.setMinValue(0);
    nubmerPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    nubmerPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
}
```

**And for the final step call this method:**

```
setNubmerPicker(yourNumberPicker,mValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display calendar using DatePickerDialog class

DatePickerDialog is used to display date picker dialog to the users where the user can pick or select any date.

https://11zon.com/android/android_datepicker_dialog.php