# How to set datePickerMode="spinner" programmatically?

Tags: android, datepicker

I need create DatePicker programmatically. And i can't use xml layout. i know set spinner in xml `datePickerMode="spinner"` and then i can use `datePicker.setSpinnersShown(true);` and `datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false)` I try add `AttributeSet` into constructor but i don't know how use it. 
Can someone help? How to create a DataPicker in spinner mode?

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33138181/2869508) worked for me with just one line.

Answer (score 9):

I've already found a post, which it would describe you this problem:

> I have found a the explanation in the following post (which describes
> a problem very similar to mine) :
>
> [Android Material Design Inline Datepicker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854762/android-material-design-inline-datepicker-issue)
>
> In fact the setCalendarViewShown(false) and setSpinnersShown(true) are
> apparently not working anymore in latest versions.
>
> We have to use an explicit XML attribute like this one
> **android:datePickerMode="spinner"**.
>
> The problem is that I'm using a DialogFragment without any XML layout
> (just a date picker dialog). So I cannot set any XML attribute.
>
> The solution is to create a dedicated custom dialog with an XML layout
> file using the requested attribute.
>
> FROM: [Impossible to make my DatePickerDialog use a spinner style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509828/impossible-to-make-my-datepickerdialog-use-a-spinner-style-programmatically)

Hope it help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set it programmatically you can you the below code but I haven't checked this code whether its working or not. Let me know if I can help you in any other way.

```
datepickerDialog_object.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
datepickerDialog_object.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from the authors' question?

Comment: He's using direct object that's why he's not able to set setspinnershown parameter.

Comment: it work for me, but only after define style theme inside constructor.

````new DatePickerDialog(view.getContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, this, year, month, day);````

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SignupPatientStep2.this,
android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

//following line to restrict future date selection
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now);

//these lines for scrollable calender. but you have to use android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog in your consructor. as @Cesar Alejandro M commented
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, Android tells me that `spinnerShown` and `calendarViewShown` are deprecated.