# Impossible to make my DatePickerDialog use a spinner style programmatically

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm using a `DialogFragment` to open a `DatePickerDialog`

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    DatePickerDialog DatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (ProfileCreationActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);
    return DatePickerDialog;
}
```

I'm getting a calendar look, where I would prefer a spinner look.

I tried:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

and

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setLayoutMode(1);
```

but it does not work.

Please note that I want the spinner look for one activity, but that I will want the calendar view for another activity. So I can not change the whole application style. I need a custom style for one activity.

Comment: What you have should work.  Things that make you go hmmmm....

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33138181/2869508) worked for me with just one line.

Answer (score 8):

I have found a the explanation in the following post (which describes a problem very similar to mine) :

[Android Material Design Inline Datepicker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854762/android-material-design-inline-datepicker-issue)

In fact the setCalendarViewShown(false) and setSpinnersShown(true) are apparently not working anymore in latest versions.

We have to use an explicit XML attribute like this one **android:datePickerMode="spinner"**.

The problem is that I'm using a DialogFragment without any XML layout (just a date picker dialog). So I cannot set any XML attribute.

The solution is to create a dedicated custom dialog with an XML layout file using the requested attribute.

Answer (score 8):

You can keep it programatically, don't need to create a new XML with the spinner, I simply changed my AppTheme(v21) style and worked ;-)

```
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="PickerDialogCustom" parent="AlertDialogCustom">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyLight500</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:positiveButtonText">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:negativeButtonText">@color/greyDark200</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/negativeButton</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/PickerDialogCustom</item>
</style>
```

remember to keep the support for <21 just adding this line, this command is ignored for >=21

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setLayoutMode(1);
```

Comment: Would it be okay if you can give a sample of negativeButton style resource to work with?

Answer (score 0):

`<item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>`Just add one line in style v21

Answer (score 0):

Give it a theme.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, expirationDatePickerDialog,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```