# How to set Android DatePicker mode to spinner for APIs below level 21

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to display a DatePickerDialog with mode spinner instead of calendar. In my styles.xml, I tried to put this attribute but it says that the minimum SDK version I should be using is API 21.

```
<item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
```

I am using minimum SDK version 18. How do I set the default date picker mode to spinner for APIs lower than API 21?

This is my Java code for my date picker:

```
public class MyDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.MyTheme, this, 0, 0, 0 );
    return datePickerDialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot change it to the spinner mode on all the APIs, but you can improve user experience: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185405/5730321

Answer (score 8):

Found an answer. Instead of creating a new DatePickerDialog in the onCreateDialog method, I just created my own layout for the date picker inflated it in the method.

Here is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dialog_date_datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:spinnersShown="true">
</DatePicker>
```

And here is the Java code:

```
public class MyDatePicker extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.datepicker, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(v).create();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: android:datePickerMode="spinner" doesn't work for all the APIs

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion
First get the API version.. If the API version is below 21 then set spinner visible and date picker invisible
To get API version. Check this link:

[Retrieving Android API version programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Let me know if this can solve your problem, I'm not sure how reliable my suggestion is

Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but still did not work. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509828/impossible-to-make-my-datepickerdialog-use-a-spinner-style-programmatically) and it looks like I need to really put the xml <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item> in the style.xml but Android Studio says it nneds to have a minSdk of 21